# Wifi networks not visible Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, dual-boot, network-manager, dell

I have a dell xps with win10 dual boot and ubuntu 16.04.
After shutting down from my windows boot and restart my ubuntu one wifi networks are not visible, not even the wireless network symbol.

I have tried

`sudo systemctl restart network-manager`

`sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-16.04 linux-firmware`

And even though the output of `rfkill list` is

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth 
    Soft blocked: no 
    Hard blocked: no 
1: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN 
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no 
2: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth 
    Soft blocked: no 
    Hard blocked: no
```

The output of `sudo lshw -C network` is still

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: Wireless 8265 / 8275
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 78
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:edc00000-edc01fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: enp0s20f0u2
       serial: 76:31:9b:d0:9a:4a
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.159 link=yes multicast=yes
```

This is so frustrating because just before booting with windows, the wifi was working without a problem. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Just a reminder 16.04 reaches end of standard support on April 22 2021. You may want to think about upgrading to 18.04 or 20.04. End of Stand Support means no more support or updates. You may not ask questions here either as 16.04 will be off topic. If you sign up for ESM you can still get security patches but that is all.

Comment: `apt purge windows` s.c.n.r  `dmesg | grep iwlwifi` I think this is the right modul.